# Redirect users from authentication URLs to signup page

Tags: 6, users, redirection

I'm using Drupal 6.

I want to redirect users from /user/login, /user/register, /user to /sign-up if the user is the anonymous user. This page would show both login and register forms together.

The only page left would be /user/password, which form I don't want to have on /sign-up.
I'm comfortable with PHP, but I'm not sure about which hooks should I use to achieve this.

PS. I already know how to print those forms on my own. My doubt is just about the URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dedicated hook for things like this, but you can implement hook_init() and then do the redirect there. Something like this:

```
function yourmodule_init() {
  global $user;
  if (in_array($_GET['q'], array('user', 'user/login', 'user/register') && !$user->uid) {
    drupal_goto('sign-up');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way, you can just enable Path module, and create URL aliases for the paths you want.

Go to admin/build/path/add and create the aliases. But this will keep the same page, if you want a more custom page, and you have already the form by your own, create a [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6), and place the form on it.

Comment: Enabling path and creating a URL alias will not redirect them, so this recomendation is not useful for me.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how I would use hook_menu to do this? Trying this: http://pastebin.com/uetJWxuJ does not work. Maybe the user/login path is protected?